# Differential Transform Method

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis

I Want to solve the following differential equation by the differential transform method

```
D[u[x], x, x] + B*D[u [x], x]^2 + A*u[x] == 0;
```

with the boundary condition

```
U[0]==0; U[1]==1;
```

and want to Plot the solution for various values of parameters A and B. I have written the statement

```
for[k = 0, k < 5, k++, 
  U[k + 2] == (-1/((k + 1) (k + 2)))*(B*
       Sum[(l + 1)*(k - l + 1)*U (l + 1)*U (k - l + 1), {l, 0, k}]
      ) + A*U[k]];
```

But this code is not working please guide

Comment: Your syntax is off. For instance, `u [x]` should be `u[x]`(no space); `u (x)` is probably wrong, you probably mean `u[x]`; `for` should be `For`; `u` is different from `U` (MMA is case-sensitive), etc etc. Please fix the syntax by reference to the help and docs first.

Comment: Searching the internet for "differential transform method mathematica code" will provide several links.

Comment: bbgodfrey searched several times but not found anything about the topic.

Comment: @ziauddin what about this? https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/SolutionOfAPDEUsingTheDifferentialTransformationMethod/